# Running two commands at the exact same time in bash

Tags: bash

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
nc ipv4 port echo "hi"
```

Question:
How do I make it say Hi  automatically right after it connected to the listener?

Comment: `echo "Hi" | nc host port` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case you want to keep the connection open after command, a fifo can be used

```
mkfifo fifo_filename

# start nc reading from fifo in background (jobs,kill can be used to monitor)
nc host port <fifo_filename &

# open file descriptor 3 to write to fifo
exec 3>fifo_filename 
echo hi >&3
...
echo bye >&3

# close file descriptor (will close the fifo and background nc will exit)
exec 3>&-
```